# How to cancel build automatically upon Sublime Text 3 exit?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there a way to ensure build is automatically cancelled upon ST3 exit if I forgot to manually do so? This is especially important for long-running tasks such as a live-update nodejs process for react webpack development in my case. Without it, I found nodejs process will continue listen on the port, preventing same build from launching later, at least on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this approach will work with node.js, but if I have a Python script that is taking too long or has reached an infinite loop I will cancel the Python task in Task Manager. Try looking for a node.js task and see if that works.

Comment: Killing using Windows task manager is exactly what I want to avoid. Your case is exceptional but my case is the norm and happens frequently so it's annoying.